# What is vb6's "Report.DetailCopies" Property in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am rewriting a vb6 Windows Application to vb.net which is handling crystal report files.
I couldn't find "report.DetailCopies property" in vb.net.

DetailCopies property can produce repeating detail sections like these:

- DetailCopies property set as 1 - 
  Page1           Page2            Page3          Page4
  Header        Header           Header         Header- 
  Detail(1)     Detail(2)        Detail(3)      Detail(4)

  Footer          Footer             Footer          Footer
- DetailCopies property set as 2 - 
  Page1           Page2            Page3          Page4
  Header        Header           Header         Header- 
  Detail(1-1)  Detail(2-1)    Detail(3-1)   Detail(4-1)
  Detail(1-2)  Detail(2-2)    Detail(3-2)   Detail(4-2)
  Footer          Footer             Footer          Footer
- DetailCopies property set as 3 - 
  Page1           Page2            Page3          Page4
  Header        Header           Header         Header- 
  Detail(1-1)  Detail(1-3)    Detail(2-1)   Detail(2-3)
  Detail(1-2)                           Detail(2-2)
  Footer          Footer             Footer          Footer

Comment: Are you looking in the right place? `Report.DetailCopies` is part of Crystal Reports, not part of VB6.

Comment: First of all thank you for your advice. Just I want know What is DetailCopies Property in vb.net.  I used this property in vb6's Crystal Reports Object. But I don't know how can I set this property in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Report.Areas.Item("D").CopiesToPrint = 1` (or 2 or 3).

Comment: Thank you for you advice. But I can't find that property "CopiesToPrint". I tried to find this Property in "ReportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections.Item(0)" and  "ReportDocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects. But couldn't find. Now I'm using VS2010 VB.NET and CrystalDecisions .NET Objects Ver.13. I think if i  find this property in my solution It will help me. Do you know where i can find this property?  thank you

Comment: Sorry, this is from an older version.